# WPF application mouse position corrupted after restoring window, hence triggers false IsMouseOvers on controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I've designed a custom window with "WindowStyle = None" and "AllowsTransparency = True". I've added custom buttons to implement minimize, maximize/restore and close features. I also have a transparent rectangle that I use to implement maximize/restore on double clicking the title bar region(which is also custom built)
Here's the code for maximizing/restoring on double clicking the title bar region

```
(this.WindowState) = (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal) ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal;
```

I wanted to add an image which exactly describes my issue, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to. I don't know why. I'm new to this page.

Comment: are you asking or tellin us? put some code or something that could figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know what you are talking about as I've noticed the same thing on my custom window. I haven't really explored a way to fix it yet though as it corrects itself. But I can confirm it is not specific to your code, just a general issue :).